# Springboot Wildfly 10 deployment error jdk.unsupported module not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, wildfly, wildfly-10

I have a Springboot v2 project with Java 1.8 and when I try to deploy my springboot project on Wildfly 10, I keep getting this error

```
19:12:25,295 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "HealthCheck.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.HealthCheck.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.HealthCheck.war\".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.HealthCheck.war:main
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: jdk.unsupported:main"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.module.service.\"deployment.HealthCheck.war\".main"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
```

I have already created a jboss-deployment-structure.xml and added the "jdk.unsupported" dependency there, I have also tried adding that to the MANIFEST.MF and I have also tried adding the missing "jdk.unsupported" dependency on the pom file under the maven-war plugin but no luck.

Comment: There is no module `jdk.unsupported` in WildFly 10. Did you create the module?

Comment: No. I believe it's something that was introduced on Java 9. I'm using Java 8 so I'm not sure which part of the code is looking for it.

Comment: That exception is coming from JBoss Modules so it's attempting to load that module. Are you sure you're using WildFly 10? If you've got a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` or a `MANIFEST.MF` entry with that module that is not correct.

Answer (score 29):

This is due to [breaking change](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/25852), which is introduced in Spring-core `5.3.*`, the change in the Spring-core library that causes the above issue is [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/25852/commits/18e7c85053120c115428cea7dbf903a4a6646de2). If you use Spring boot version `2.4.*` then surely you will face this issue as it pulls the transitive dependency of Spring-core `5.3.*`. The pragmatic approach is either to upgrade the wildfly version if possible(The latest version is `22.0.1.Final`, the `wildfly 10.1.0.Final`
was released nearly 5 years back on Aug 19, 2016) or downgrade your Spring boot version to `'2.3.*.RELEASE'`.

---

**Workaround**
Please follow the below workaround for those who cannot upgrade the Wildfly server but in the situation to use the latest Spring version(`5.3.*`). The actual issue is the Spring-core 5.3.x contains the `MANIFEST.MF` file entry `Dependencies: jdk.unsupported`. If we remove the particular entry from the jar's MANIFEST.MF file we can use the Spring-core 5.3.x in the Wildfly 10.X version itself.

To patch the 5.3.x and pull it into the classpath, the following steps are required:

1. As the jar file itself an archive opens it with `7-Zip`/`winrar` or with any file archive utility tools. Open the `MANIFEST.MF` and remove the last line `Dependencies: jdk.unsupported` and save the change.
2. Put the patched jar file into your project folder i.e., `lib`
3. Exclude the `Spring-core 5.3.x` at the project level and enforce the build tool to use the patched library of `Spring-core 5.3.x` from the project directory and add it to your classpath. I have provided the snippet for `gradle` users

```
dependencies {
    //Adding the patched jar into the classpath from a project directory
    compile files('lib/spring-core-5.3.3.jar')
}

configurations.all {
    //Excluding the spring-core-5.3.3.jar at the project level
    exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-core'
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped my month-blocked issue. It worked. +1

Comment: @XsoluteIm, I have added the workaround approach that I used for my project

Comment: Unless I use maven for project, your workaround helped so much, thanks!

Comment: i had another errors with maven but succeeded with gradle easily. thx a lot!!

Answer (score 25):

I found a better solution, based on creating a new fake module named **jdk.unsupported** on jboss or wildfly.

In my case, I can't upgrade the JBoss EAP 7.1, and I want to keep updated to the latest version of Spring.

So what I did is to create a new fake module under **modules/system/layers/base** folder and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Can you describe how you did this?

Comment: You should create a new module for JBoss. It's easy to do.
1. Create a new folder folder under *$JBOSS_PATH/modules/system/layers/base* named *jdk/unsupported/main*
2. Create a new file under the *main* folder named *module.xml* with the following content:
´´´´
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="jdk.unsupported">
</module>
´´´´

Comment: Thx a lot, that's an nice and easy solution to ensure app compatibility to older JBoss versions.

Comment: I've applied your idea and works perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I faced exactly same issue and resolved it by upgrading wildfly 10 to 20 with java 8.
My spring boot version was 2.4.0
Alternatively, i degraded my spring boot version to 1.5.8.RELEASE and was able to successfully run on wildfly 10.

Answer (score 0):

We are using wildfly 11. and the max version of spring boot we could use is 2.3.11 without this issue. starting from 2.3.12, this error appears.