# Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: jdk.unsupported

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, java-8, war, jboss-eap-7

{"WFLYCTL0080: Servicios fallidos" => {"jboss.module.service."deployment.telemedicina.war".main" => "WFLYSRV0179: Error al cargar el módulo: deployment.telemedicina.war
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: jdk.unsupported"}}

this error is JBOSS-EAP7.1 IN EAP7.2 AN EAP7.3, IT DOES NOT HAPPEN

Comment: There are no modules in JDK 8.

Comment: Do you have a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` with a module dependency on `jdk.unsupported`? That module was not in JBoss EAP 7.1.

Comment: Maybe [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65100927/2711488) can help.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that there was a change in Spring Framework 5.3 that is causing the error. If you use a newer version of JBoss/Wildfly, or regress your SpringFramework to less than 2.5.~ it will fix this issue.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24686